# Authenticate with Kerberos to a CIFS share provided by OpenSolaris

Tags: authentication, kerberos, opensolaris, cifs

I have an OpenSolaris server (running snv_128a) which I have (a) joined to an Active Directory domain and (b) configured to export some filesystems via CIFS:

```
# sharemgr show -vp
default nfs=()
zfs
    zfs/rpool/export/public nfs=() smb=()
      rpool_export_public=/export/public
```

I can successfully access this share using a username and password:

```
$ smbclient //muadib/rpool_export_public
Enter lars's password: 
Domain=[SEAS] OS=[Windows NT 4.0] Server=[NT LAN Manager 4.0]
smb: \>
```

I have valid kerberos credentials.  For example, I can ssh to the same OpenSolaris box using GSSAPI authentication:

```
$ ssh -v muadib
.
.
.
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Authentication succeeded (gssapi-with-mic).
```

But I'm unable to access the CIFS share using Kerberos:

```
smbclient -k //muadib/rpool_export_public
Domain=[SEAS] OS=[Windows NT 4.0] Server=[NT LAN Manager 4.0]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

I'm not getting any useful error messages anywhere.  In fact, the only message being logged is this:

```
Dec 11 13:54:57 muadib smbsrv: [ID 138215 kern.notice] NOTICE: 
smbd[NT Authority\Anonymous]: rpool_export_public access denied: IPC only
```

I am able to authenticate with Kerberos to network shares elsewhere on the network.

I haven't been able to find much documentation addressing this particular aspect of CIFS service on OpenSolaris.  Most of what I've found gets as far as "this is how you enable CIFS" and "this is how you create a share" and then stops.  If you've got this working or know of some resources to help me out I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current builds of OpenSolaris do not support Kerberos authentication for CIFS shares.  The feature is apparently "forthcoming".  References:

- http://bugs.opensolaris.org/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6791210
- http://arc.opensolaris.org/caselog/PSARC/2009/673/